# Pyroscope triggering error in Node.js (regenerator-runtime)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to integrate a Pyroscope profiling to my node server.

Here is how I use it:

**profiler.ts**

```
import Pyroscope from "@pyroscope/nodejs";

Pyroscope.init({
  serverAddress: "...",
  appName: "app-backend"
});

Pyroscope.start();
```

**index.ts**

```
// ...
import "./profiler.js";
// ...
```

For TypeScript, I've set `compilerOptions.target` and `compilerOptions.module` to "esnext" (`"type": "module"` in package.json).

When I'm using Node v18 or v19, I get an error when installing the `@pyroscope/nodejs` dependency:

```
error /home/.../node_modules/pprof: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/.../node_modules/pprof
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
node-pre-gyp info using node@19.9.0 | linux | x64
```

It installs when using node v16. But then after compiling the TS and starting the node server, I get:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/.../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime' imported from /home/.../node_modules/@pyroscope/nodejs/dist/esm/index.js
Did you mean to import regenerator-runtime/runtime.js?
```

I'm on Manjaro if that helps. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try installing pyroscope with

```
npm --build-from-source install @pyroscope/nodejs
```

Before doing that it would also be a good idea to delete the `node_modules` directory.
If that doesn't work you can still try installing `node-pre-gyp` globally with

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```

I hope one of these works for you

Comment: Thanks for the response. The second option doesn't work. For the first, why bcrypt?

Comment: @ostrebler Sorry, fixed it. Did installing pyroscope with `--build-from-source` help?